# How to write CUDA code to print out the CUDA capable devices?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, gpgpu

How to write the CUDA code to print out the CUDA capable devices on the computer.

Comment: Take a look at the cuda deviceQuery sample code

Comment: I found one website ("http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~xyuan/cda5125/examples/lect24/devicequery.cu") which has done this. Please let me know if you know some specific example. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is directly from the nvidia developer site:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() {
  int nDevices;

  cudaGetDeviceCount(&nDevices);
  for (int i = 0; i < nDevices; i++) {
    cudaDeviceProp prop;
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, i);
    printf("Device Number: %d\n", i);
    printf("  Device name: %s\n", prop.name);
    printf("  Memory Clock Rate (KHz): %d\n",
           prop.memoryClockRate);
    printf("  Memory Bus Width (bits): %d\n",
           prop.memoryBusWidth);
    printf("  Peak Memory Bandwidth (GB/s): %f\n\n",
           2.0*prop.memoryClockRate*(prop.memoryBusWidth/8)/1.0e6);
  }
}
```

From their documentation:

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-enumeration

```
int deviceCount;
cudaGetDeviceCount (&deviceCount);
int device;
for (device = 0; device < deviceCount; ++device) {
    cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
    cudaGetDeviceProperties (&deviceProp, device);
    printf ("Device %d has compute capability %d.%d.\n", device,
        deviceProp.major, deviceProp.minor);
}
```

## Note

Devices are enumerated from 1...

Comment: Thanks for comment. I tried and its printing the device #:, Memory clock rate:, Memory Bus width: and Peak Memory:. Thanks

Comment: if the answer works for you please accept and upvote

Comment: @Ahmad Masud Thanks. I accepted the answer, but since i am new the system doesn't let me to upvote. i hope tech support can help me.